# Blazor - HTML tag inside of c# bound bool switch

Tags: c#, html, tags, blazor

I want to add a icon into a button context depending on a bool.

How to implement a HTML tag into a c# bound bool switch?

```
<button type="button"> 
   @(SwitchBool? "Save" : @"<i class='\u0022'fa fa-pen'\u0022'></i>")
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="() => SwitchBool = !SwitchBool"> 
   @if(SwitchBool)
   {
       <text>Save</text>
   }
   else
   {
       <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
   }
</button>

@code {
    private bool SwitchBool;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think C# likes to have different types for the output of a ternary.  But you can just build whatever string you want and cast it to `MarkupString`

```
@((MarkupString)(SwitchBool ? "Save" : "<i class='fa fa-pen'/>"))
```

I don't like this, though, as you really have to process the entire line to understand what it's doing.  I'd rather just take the extra lines to write a conditional.  Also, give your bool a meaningful name:

```
<button>
    @if (ReadyToSave)
    {
        <span>"Save"</span>
    }
    else 
    {
        <i class='fa fa-pen'/>
    }
</button>
```

The `if . . . else` could be crammed into a single line, but I really wouldn't suggest that.